# Getting a value from a Spinner selection

Tags: java, android, spinner

I want a spinner to return an value to me once the user has selected an item.

I know I could use a button and then use spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() in the OnClick(), but I want the value to be returned as soon as the user has selected amongst the spinner choices. Thus, I had thought to use an OnItemSelectedListener.

```
int valueINeed;
subGoalSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
            //I now want to somehow get the value of the index for use outside of this code block
}
```

I can obviously not use a straight `return` statement as the method has a `void` return type. Furthermore, I cannot set `valueINeed = index` unless I make valueINeed `final`. I am not sure I want to do that as what happens if the user changes his/her mind and I need to reassign the value?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the point in setting the selected index inside the selected event if you are not doing anything with it right away?  The spinner already contains a method as you described to get the index when you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TronicZomB's answer is correct, but you won't be notified when the global variable changes.  If you need to do something with `valueINeed` as soon as it's changed in the `Spinner`, you have two options:

1. Take the code that uses `valueINeed` and put it all inside of the `onItemSelected` function
2. Create a seperate function that you call from within the `onItemSelected` function.

Example of #2:

```
subGoalSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
    {
        valueINeed = subGoalSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        updateView(valueINeed);
    }
}
```

In this case, `updateView` is a function that takes in `valueINeed` as a parameter and does something with it (like updating a `TextView`).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! I kept trying to think of ways to have onItemSelected take an argument...for some reason it never occurred to me to make my own method XD

Additionally, when I want to make my variable global, would I have to make it  `final valueINeed`if I were to place it sometime before I declare `subGoalSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(` etc ?

Comment: No, if you made it final you wouldn't be able to modify it :)  Just declare it directly inside your class, and outside of any methods like `onCreate`.  Simply do a `int valueINeed;`

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable `int valueINeed;` as a global variable. Than you can use the following:

```
subGoalSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        valueINeed = subGoalSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        //I now want to somehow get the value of the index for use outside of this code block
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, while I had already thought of this, I was looking more to be notified when the change in the global variable had occurred, and thus accepted another answer